# Update my local branch from the same branch of remote

Tags: git

I have pushed one branch (branch-a) with one commit to remote and now my friend has checked out my remote branch (origin/branch-a), made some changes, amended the commit, and pushed to the same branch(i.e origin/branch-a)

Now, I have to update my local branch (branch-a). My local branch will not have an old commit rather it will have my friend's commit. How can I achieve that?

> To give the question more clarity, I'd like to add some details which may be required.

```
git status

on branch 'branch-a'
'branch-a' is ahead of 1 commit of the 'origin/master'
```

I added this one commit to branch-a and push this branch with one commit to the remote origin.

I have pushed my local branch like this

```
git push origin branch-a
```

> My friend has created a new branch and checked out my remote branch (origin/branch-a), made some changes, applied the upstream branch to `origin/master` as my branch-a was also a keeping tracking of origin/master, amended the commit, and pushed to the same branch(i.e origin/branch-a)

> Now, I have to update my local branch (branch-a). My local branch will not have an old commit rather it will have my friend's commit. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you do any changes after pushing to remote?

Comment: no, I didn't do any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If he simply added a new commit on top of yours you can use git pull. If he really amended your commit and force pushed the branch, first tell him not to do this to branches other people work with and then simply delete your local branch and checkout the remote branch again.

Comment: There is nothing like that. Actually, I want to make some changes after updating my local branch then I will amend the friend's commit again and pushed to the same remote branch.

Comment: i see, still after you checkout the branch again you have the most up to date version of it locally, you can then do what you described with it, go try ;-)

Comment: I have deleted the local branch and then checked out to the same remote branch. I have a question is this the only way to do this? I mean without deleting the local branch can't I update it with the latest commit which is amended by others?

Comment: As far as I am aware not, the branches are not in sync anymore and I think git will reject you altogether because of this. But that's not an issue really, normally you don't keep ammending commits over and over, you simply make changes and push a new commit. Remember commit is a piece of history. You should not rewrite your git history all the time like this and you will have no problems.

Comment: I have gone with your approach and I achieved what I was expecting. I have not deleted the branch instead created a new branch and pushed it like this `git push origin branch-b:branch-a`.

Comment: Hah, I am glad to hear that! What did you create that branch from if I may ask?

Comment: I created a branch-b `git checkout -b branch-b origin/branch-a` then I set the upstream branch to origin/master. `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master`